# Android scheduled notification error

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I'm using this code to make 'scheduled notification' so notification would appear even if the app is not workign.

But I have some crashes at my Nexus with `Android-M` that appear randomly when I'm using my phone (during phone call, when using YT app and so on).

Is it a good or a bad way to make scheduled notifications?

```
private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, int delay) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mCtx, NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, (int) System.currentTimeMillis());
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mCtx, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    long futureInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + delay;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
}
```

**EDIT:** I actually caught exception but still don't know how to fix it.

```
Process: com.ko.makemyhaircut, PID: 2184
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.ko.makemyhaircut.model.NotificationPublisher: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.net.Uri android.app.Notification.sound' on a null object reference
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2732)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.net.Uri android.app.Notification.sound' on a null object reference
                                                     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:213)
                                                     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:194)
                                                     at com.ko.makemyhaircut.model.NotificationPublisher.onReceive(NotificationPublisher.java:17)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2725)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: did you ever found the solution to this? I seem to have it as well on a very rare phone

Comment: @FabioC , unfortunately not found solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and it turned out I was using a global variable for the context which turned out to be null. I can see that you are doing the same. Your variable

```
mCtx
```

contains the context. If that is null, then you will get that error.
It is never a good idea to save the context in a global variable.

Comment: Yes, that was a bad practice. Thanks!